# `?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>` when using rust celery

Tags: rust

when I defined the rust celery app like this:

```
use std::{error::Error};
use structopt::StructOpt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    test1(CeleryOpt::Consume);
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(
    name = "celery_app",
    about = "Run a Rust Celery producer or consumer.",
    setting = structopt::clap::AppSettings::ColoredHelp,
)]
pub enum CeleryOpt {
    Consume,
    Produce {
        #[structopt(possible_values = &["add", "buggy_task", "bound_task", "long_running_task"])]
        tasks: Vec<String>,
    },
}

async fn test1(opt: CeleryOpt) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send>> {
    let redis_addr =
        std::env::var("REDIS_ADDR").unwrap_or_else(|_| "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/".into());
    let my_app = celery::app!(
        broker = RedisBroker { redis_addr },
        tasks = [
        ],
        task_routes = [
            "buggy_task" => "buggy-queue",
            "*" => "celery",
        ],
        prefetch_count = 2,
        heartbeat = Some(10)
    )
    .await?;

    match opt {
        CeleryOpt::Consume => {
            my_app.display_pretty().await;
            my_app.consume_from(&["celery", "buggy-queue"]).await?;
        }
        CeleryOpt::Produce { tasks } => {
            if tasks.is_empty() {
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    };

    my_app.close().await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

the compiler shows error:

```
`?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>`
the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
```

I have to return the function as Send enable because I will put this function into a spawn thread, the thread need a response with Send enabled. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
celery="0.5.3"
```